# Can you have multiple Working Holiday Visas (WHV) in Europe?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, working-holiday

Can you you have let's say a 1 year working holiday visa in Netherlands and a 1 year working holiday visa in Germany, Belgium, Estonia etc. at the same time? or can you only have one at a time?